# Best way to unserialize within an array

Tags: php, serialization

I have an array which contains serialized data similar to the example below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [data] => a:2:{s:6:"Series";a:1:{s:11:"description";s:11:"hello world";}s:4:"Type";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}}
            [created] => 2009-10-12 18:45:35
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [data] => a:2:{s:6:"Series";a:1:{s:11:"description";s:11:"hello world";}s:4:"Type";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}}
            [created] => 2009-10-12 17:39:41

        )
    ...
)
```

What would be the best way to unserialize the value of the data key and replace the serialized data with its contents?

I have tried looping using a reference which works although the last two entries in the array are identical when they shouldn't be.

```
foreach($data as &$item) {
    $item['data'] = unserialize($item['data']);
}
```

Comment: Your way looks fine.  What do you mean about the "he last two entries in the array are identical when they shouldn't be"?

Comment: For some reason the last result in the array is a clone of the one before it. I feel silly, I overcomplicated this problem for myself, the answer is fairly obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another way:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    $data[$key]['data'] = unserialize($item['data']);
}
```

Or:

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $item['data'] = unserialize($item['data']);
    $data[] = $item;
}
$data = array_slice($data, count($data)/2);
```

Comment: I hope you didn’t take the latter example. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using references in a `foreach`-loop can introduce hard-to-track and mysterious behaviours. You should use a simple `for`-loop instead.

```
$num = count($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
{
    $item[$i]['data'] = unserialize($item[$i]['data']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will work :

```
$data2 = array ();
foreach($data as $item) {
    $item['data'] = unserialize($item['data']);
    $data2[] = $item;
}
```

If you want not to use another array :

```
foreach($data as $k => $item) {
    $data[$k]['data'] = unserialize($item['data']);
}
```